# python if statement not working

Tags: python

My Python code isn't working. It outputs "HI!" regardless of the input.

```
WifiPswd = '3JUFJF34AF3LLRAC'
UsrIn = ''
print("Maxi AI v0.2 Booting...")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("....")
print("Boot Succesful")
print(" Hi, I'm Maxi Your Virtual Assistant! ")
UsrIn = input(" ")
if UsrIn == "Hi" or "hi" or "Hello" or "hello" or "Hey" or "hey" or       "Hi!" or "hi!" or "Hello!" or "hello!" or "Hey!" or "hey!" or "Hi?" or "hi?" or "Hello?" or "hello?" or "Hey?" or "hey?" or "Hi." or "hi." or "Hello." or "hello." or "Hey." or "hey." or "Bonjour" or "bonjour" or "Bonjour!" or "bonjour!" or "Bonjour?" or "bonjour?" or "Bonjour." or "bonjour." or "Hola" or "hola" or "Hola!" or "hola!" or "Hola?" or "hola?" or "Hola." or "hola." : 
      print("Hi!")
elif UsrIn == "Bye" or "bye" or "Bye-Bye" or "bye-bye" or "See you later" or "see you later" or "Bye!" or "bye!" or "Bye-Bye!" or "bye-bye!" or "See you later!" or "see you later!" or "See You Later" or "See You Later!" or "Bye-bye" or "Bye-bye!" or "Bye." or "bye." or "Bye-Bye." or "bye-bye." or "Bye-bye." or "See you later." or "see you later." or "See You Later." or "Au Revoir" or "au revoir" or "Au revoir" or "Au Revoir!" or "au revoir!" or "Au revoir!" or "Au Revoir." or "au revoir." or "Ciao" or "ciao" or "Ciao!" or "ciao!" or "Ciao." or "ciao." :      
      print("Bye...")
elif UsrIn == "Wifi Password" or "Wifi password" or "wifi password" :
      print( WifiPswd )
else:
      print("I don't Understand.")
```

Ive tried using multiple ifs instead of Elifs but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try to improve you code. For example for wifi password you can use `elif UsrIn.lower() == 'wifi password'`.
For greetings you can look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). It makes your code waay shorter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to have the check after each part of the if statement.

Right now after it checks for "Hi" reads true because 'hi' is a true value
Change all of your stements to something like

```
if UsrIn == "Hi" or UsrIn =="hi" or UsrIn =="Hello" or UsrIn =="hello" ...
```

That way it actually checks

Comment: It might also be more expressive to use some kind of iterable: `if UsrIn.lower() in {"hi", "hello"...}`

Comment: how would I repeat this code infinitely.